# Bootstrap font overwrite with different fonts for heading and body

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, overwrite

I have been trying to apply different bootstrap fonts to my headings and different font to the body. I have looked at various sources and found solutions only on Changing the overall font style of the bootstrap css by overriding.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
</head>
```

from this link [Bootstrap override using custom.css](https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/customize-bootstrap/)

The code inside custom.css is given below

```
body{
   font-family: 'Calibri', arial; 
}

.grid{
   border:solid 1px #000;
}

.img-fix{
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
}
```

But this changed all the fonts in the Bootstrap into 'Calibri' font. But I want to apply 'Calibri' only to the headings and any other font style to body such as 'open-sans' to the text body.
Please let me know how to achieve this. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can apply it to ur heading or whatever tags u want like this

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
     font-family: 'Calibri', arial, sans-sarif; 
}
```

and for body if u want to apply open sans do it like this

```
body{
     font-family: 'open-sans', arial, sans-sarif; 
}
```